# "transaction interface" error when updating table on linked server

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm getting this error when trying to update a db2 database that is a linked server on our SQL Server db.

> ERROR:root:('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "IBMDA400" for linked server "iSeries" does not support the required transaction interface. (7390) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I am connecting to sql server via pyodbc and can run sql scripts with no issues. Here is the sql I get the error with

```
sql3 = " exec ('UPDATE SVCEN2DEV.SRVMAST SET SVRMVD = ? WHERE svtype != ''*DCS-'' AND svcid = ? and svacct = ? ') AT [iSeries]"
db.execute(sql3, (row[2],srvid,row[0]))
db.commit()
```

And just in case here is my connection string  using pyodbc:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+ Config_Main.dbServer +";DATABASE="+ Config_Main.encludeName +";UID="+ Config_Main.encludeUser +";PWD=" + Config_Main.encludePass)
db = conn.cursor()
```

Also note that this query runs just fine in SSMS. I have also tried the openquery method but had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, have you met [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) ?

Comment: @alfasin This is an automated process with no input.

Comment: Oh, in that case it's okay to write sloppy code...

Comment: Try adding a `conn.autocommit = True` statement immediately after you call `pyodbc.connect`.

Comment: @GordThompson That worked! So the commit statement after the .execute doesn't work because the linked server wants to commit the changes before returning to python? Does that sound like an accurate statement?

Comment: @alfasin Hi, you are correct and I have edited my sql. Is this the correct way to protect yourself from sql injection?

Comment: @Pintang yes looks much better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [DB API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specifies that, by default, connections should open with autocommit "off". This results in all database operations being performed in a transaction that must be explicitly committed (or rolled back) in the Python code.

When a pyodbc connection with `autocommit = False` (the default) sends an UPDATE to the SQL Server, that UPDATE is enclosed in a Local Transaction managed by SQL Server. When the SQL Server determines that the target table is on a Linked Server it tries to promote the transaction to a Distributed Transaction managed by [MSDTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator). If the connection technology used to manage the Linked Server does not support Distributed Transactions then the operation will fail.

This issue can often be avoided by ensuring that the pyodbc connection has autocommit enabled, either by

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
```

or

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cnxn.autocommit = True
```

That will send each SQL statement individually, without being wrapped in an implicit transaction.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. +1