# How to perform two_phase transaction in python for MSSQL & DB2 without ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, db2-400

I want to perform two_phase transaction in python for mssql & DB2 using sql alchemy. For mssql my connection string is

> "mssql+pyodbc://****:*****@192.168.***.***:1433/SourceDB?driver=FreeTDS&; odbc_options='TDS_Version=7.2'"

when I am trying to begin_twophase its gives an error as "Not ImplmentedError"

```
conn.begin_twophase()  #conn is an connection object
```

Is there any mssql driver in python which support distributed transactions?

For sqlalchemycore its not supported.
[issue already raised at sqlalchemy site and they marked as "wont fix"](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/4173/begin_twophase-method-throws-error-as-not)

Any other solution ? Kindly help.

Comment: ORMs have nothing to do with distributed transactions. It isn't the job of the *driver* either - you need a transaction coordinator that will connect with the databases and coordinate the transactions. On Windows, that's MS DTC. You can "cheat" though, and add one database to the other as a linked server. Eg, add DB2 as a linked server on SQL Server. When you execute a query that works with the linked server to SQL Server, the server will automatically start a distributed transaction through MS DTC

Comment: BTW that issue is 2 years old and probably invalid. FreeTDS is a very limited driver too, it doesn't even support query paramters. SQL Server runs on Linux now. Microsoft always had its own version SQL Server ODBC driver for Linux which was greatly improved before SQL Server on Linux was released. SQL Server supported distributed transactions and XA in 2000 already - I used it under COM+ services to perform distributed transactions between SQL Server and Oracle on Unix behind Tuxedo.

Comment: If anything that bug essentially says "SQL Alchemy doesn't support XA transactions with any database". MySQL didn't even *have* transactions back in the 2000s, when all the major databases established and implemented the XA standard

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos re: *"[supporting distributed transactions] isn't the job of the driver either"* - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47288391/2144390) seems to suggest that a SQL Server instance with a DB2 linked server may not be able to support distributed transactions if the "OLE DB provider ... does not support the required transaction interface". It certainly looks like the DB2 driver (or "provider" in this case) needs to support distributed transactions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @GordThompson no it doesn't. `Also note that this query runs just fine in SSMS.`. SSMS is just the *client* tool. It doesn't perform any magic, it simply sends commands to the server for execution. In fact, it looks like you found that problem wasn't related to the *driver* but the autocommit setting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The query worked in SSMS because by default IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is OFF (a.k.a. "autocommit mode") for an SSMS session, so no transactions were involved. If that query had been preceded by a BEGIN TRANSACTION statement then it presumably would have failed.